# How can I guarantee that a Swift closure (referencing Firebase) fully executes before I move on?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, grand-central-dispatch

I have multiple query snapshots with closures and some of them are using the data supplied by the query that came before it.

I have read up on GCD and I've tried to implement a DispatchGroup with .enter() and .leave() but I am apparently doing something wrong.

If somebody can help me by laying out exactly how to force one task to be performed before another, that would solve my problem.

If you can't tell, I am somewhat new to this so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//MARK: Get all userActivities with distance(All Code)
static func getAllChallengesWithDistanceAllCode(activity:String, completion: @escaping ([Challenge]) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let currUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    var currUserName:String?
    var distanceSetting:Int?
    var senderAverage:Double?
    var senderBestScore:Int?
    var senderMatchesPlayed:Double?
    var senderMatchesWon:Double?
    var senderWinPercentage:Double?
    var validUserActivities = [Challenge]()
    
    db.collection("users").document(currUserID).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil || snapshot == nil {
            return
        }
        currUserName = snapshot?.data()!["userName"] as? String
        distanceSetting = snapshot?.data()!["distanceSetting"] as? Int
    }
    db.collection("userActivities").document(String(currUserID + activity)).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        //check for error
        //MARK: changed snapshot to shapshot!.data() below (possible debug tip)
        if error != nil {
            //is error or no data..??
            return
        }
        if snapshot!.data() == nil {
            return
        }
        //get profile from data proprty of snapshot
        if let uActivity = snapshot!.data() {
            senderBestScore = uActivity["bestScore"] as? Int
            senderMatchesPlayed = uActivity["played"] as? Double
            senderMatchesWon = uActivity["wins"] as? Double
            senderAverage = uActivity["averageScore"] as? Double
            senderWinPercentage = round((senderMatchesWon! / senderMatchesPlayed!) * 1000) / 10
        }
    }
    
    if distanceSetting != nil {
        db.collection("userActivities").whereField("activity", isEqualTo: activity).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("something went wrong... \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            }
            if snapshot == nil || snapshot?.documents.count == 0 {
                print("something went wrong... \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                return
            }
            if snapshot != nil && error == nil {
                let uActivitiesData = snapshot!.documents
                for uActivity in uActivitiesData {
                    let userID = uActivity["userID"] as! String
                    UserService.determineDistance(otherUserID: userID) { (determinedDistance) in
                        if determinedDistance! <= distanceSetting! && userID != currUserID {
                            var x = Challenge()
                            //Sender
                            x.senderUserID = currUserID
                            x.senderUserName = currUserName
                            x.senderAverage = senderAverage
                            x.senderBestScore = senderBestScore
                            x.senderMatchesPlayed = senderMatchesPlayed
                            x.senderMatchesWon = senderMatchesWon
                            x.senderWinPercentage = senderWinPercentage
                            //Receiver
                            x.receiverUserID = userID
                            x.receiverUserName = uActivity["userName"] as? String
                            x.receiverAverage = uActivity["averageScore"] as? Double
                            x.receiverBestScore = uActivity["bestScore"] as? Int
                            if (uActivity["played"] as! Double) < 1 || (uActivity["played"] as? Double) == nil {
                                x.receiverMatchesPlayed = 0
                                x.receiverMatchesWon = 0
                                x.receiverWinPercentage = 0
                            } else {
                                x.receiverMatchesPlayed = uActivity["played"] as? Double
                                x.receiverMatchesWon = uActivity["wins"] as? Double
                                x.receiverWinPercentage = ((uActivity["wins"] as! Double) / (uActivity["played"] as! Double) * 1000).rounded() / 10
                            }
                            if uActivity["playStyle"] as? String == nil {
                                x.receiverPlayStyle = "~No PlayStyle~"
                            } else {
                                x.receiverPlayStyle = uActivity["playStyle"] as! String
                            }
                            x.activity = activity
                            
                            //append to array
                            validUserActivities.append(x)
                        }
                    }
                }
                completion(validUserActivities)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than trying to use GCD, have you considered just using callbacks/completion handlers? You're already using one when calling this function and another on `UserService.determineDistance`, so I'm assuming you're familiar with that pattern.

Comment: A little hint: If you provide sample code, please remove _everything_ that is not _absolutely_ necessary to reproduce the issue. Many people don't just have the time to navigate through all the complex code just to find out what you mean. If you already know that one snapshot closure needs data from another, just try to reduce the code to exactly this.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Thank you for the feedback! I'll be sure to make a point of minimizing superfluous code next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

1. Add a constant before the for-in loop counting the total number of query results

```
    let documentCount = snapshot?.documents.count
```

2. Add a counter before the for-in loop starting at 0

```
    var runCounter = 0
```

3. Increment the counter with each iteration at the beginning of the for-in loop

```
    runCounter += 1
```

4. Add code to the end of the for-in loop to call the completion handler to return the results

```
    if runCounter == documentCount {
                                                
        completion(validChallenges)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
static func getAllChallengesWithDistanceAllCode(activity:String, completion: @escaping ([Challenge]) -> Void) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let currUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    var currUserName:String?
    var distanceSetting:Int?
    var senderAverage:Double?
    var senderBestScore:Int?
    var senderMatchesPlayed:Double?
    var senderMatchesWon:Double?
    var senderWinPercentage:Double?
    var validUserActivities = [Challenge]()
    
db.collection("users").document(currUserID).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
    if error != nil || snapshot == nil {
        return
    }
    currUserName = snapshot?.data()!["userName"] as? String
    distanceSetting = snapshot?.data()!["distanceSetting"] as? Int
    db.collection("userActivities").document(String(currUserID + activity)).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
    //check for error
    //MARK: changed snapshot to shapshot!.data() below (possible debug tip)
    if error != nil {
        //is error or no data..??
        return
    }
    if snapshot!.data() == nil {
        return
    }
    //get profile from data proprty of snapshot
    if let uActivity = snapshot!.data() {
        senderBestScore = uActivity["bestScore"] as? Int
        senderMatchesPlayed = uActivity["played"] as? Double
        senderMatchesWon = uActivity["wins"] as? Double
        senderAverage = uActivity["averageScore"] as? Double
        senderWinPercentage = round((senderMatchesWon! / senderMatchesPlayed!) * 1000) / 10
        if snapshot != nil && error == nil {
            let uActivitiesData = snapshot!.documents
            for uActivity in uActivitiesData {
                let userID = uActivity["userID"] as! String
                UserService.determineDistance(otherUserID: userID) { (determinedDistance) in
                    if determinedDistance! <= distanceSetting! && userID != currUserID {
                        var x = Challenge()
                        //Sender
                        x.senderUserID = currUserID
                        x.senderUserName = currUserName
                        x.senderAverage = senderAverage
                        x.senderBestScore = senderBestScore
                        x.senderMatchesPlayed = senderMatchesPlayed
                        x.senderMatchesWon = senderMatchesWon
                        x.senderWinPercentage = senderWinPercentage
                        //Receiver
                        x.receiverUserID = userID
                        x.receiverUserName = uActivity["userName"] as? String
                        x.receiverAverage = uActivity["averageScore"] as? Double
                        x.receiverBestScore = uActivity["bestScore"] as? Int
                        if (uActivity["played"] as! Double) < 1 || (uActivity["played"] as? Double) == nil {
                            x.receiverMatchesPlayed = 0
                            x.receiverMatchesWon = 0
                            x.receiverWinPercentage = 0
                        } else {
                            x.receiverMatchesPlayed = uActivity["played"] as? Double
                            x.receiverMatchesWon = uActivity["wins"] as? Double
                            x.receiverWinPercentage = ((uActivity["wins"] as! Double) / (uActivity["played"] as! Double) * 1000).rounded() / 10
                        }
                        if uActivity["playStyle"] as? String == nil {
                            x.receiverPlayStyle = "~No PlayStyle~"
                        } else {
                            x.receiverPlayStyle = uActivity["playStyle"] as! String
                        }
                        x.activity = activity
                        
                        //append to array
                        validUserActivities.append(x)
                    }
                }
            }
            completion(validUserActivities)
        }
    }
}
    }
}
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this before and the completion handler is called before the for in loop. My solution is posted below.